# imports of *.pch files are ignored for new classes - why?

Tags: xcode4.3, pch

I have a project created with Xcode 3 and now want to update it using Xcode 4.3.

I used a `*.pch` file which works great - however on all the new classes I create now in Xcode4.3 this pch is ignored and I need to write the imports manually for these classes.

Is this a bug or a feature :-) ?

**Is there anything special I need to do to get the pch file working for the new classes files?**

Many thanks